# kivy video streaming

Tags: video, camera, streaming, kivy

I'm new to Kivy and looking to stream video to a display I'm making. I'm streaming the video from an external camera, so I'll only have it's IP address, and it won't be directly connected to the computer. Does anyone know how I can display the stream using the video or camera widgets, or any other way I can accomplish this?

Comment: not sure but this might be a good place to start http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.core.camera.html

Answer (score 3):

You can stream video using the [`Video` widget](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.video.html), as long as the media backend supports streaming and the media type of the video. On a desktop, you can just type the following command line:

```
python -m kivy.uix.video http://www.debone.com/VivVilConGminorRV578.mpg
```

and it will play (if supported). Works for me on Ubuntu 14.04.

Here's the `App` that runs in `kivy.uix.video`:

```
class VideoApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.v = Video(source=sys.argv[1], state='play')
        self.v.bind(state=self.replay)
        return self.v

    def replay(self, *args):
        if self.v.state == 'stop':
            self.v.state = 'play'
```

If you need to test it on a mobile device, you can just make a simple `main.py`:

```
from kivy.uix.video import VideoApp
VideoApp().run()
```